# MySQL how to get query with 17 month date interval which shows current month plus 5 months ahead

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm quite new to SQL and i have issues with a query i find quite complex.

So i'm trying to create a query that shows a 17 month date interval.
In that interval it has to show the what the current month and current date is.
Then it has to compare that date with the months before current date.

I'll then use the data i get in a Highcharts chart.

This is what my current query and table looks like.

```
SELECT
    MONTH(s_order_main.added_date)                  AS iMonth,
    s_order_main.channel                            AS strChannel,
    COUNT(DISTINCT s_order_styles.s_order_style_id) AS iOrderCount,
    SUM(DISTINCT s_order_styles.sales_price)        AS fTurnover
FROM
    s_order_main
INNER JOIN
    s_order_styles ON
        s_order_styles.s_order_main_id = s_order_main.id
WHERE
    s_order_main.channel
    && s_order_main.order_type = 'pre'
    && YEAR(s_order_main.added_date) = YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 17 MONTH)
GROUP BY
    MONTH(s_order_main.added_date)
;
```

| iMonth | strChannel | iOrderCount | fTurnover |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | normal | 2234 | 33048.66 |
| 2 | normal | 6638 | 66711.96 |
| 3 | normal | 4266 | 30742.70 |
| 4 | normal | 171 | 766.10 |
| 5 | normal | 90 | 926.55 |
| 6 | normal | 1254 | 12334.04 |
| 7 | normal | 921 | 2990.35 |
| 8 | normal | 9469 | 46407.63 |
| 9 | normal | 5837 | 31623.17 |
| 10 | normal | 70 | 305.03 |
| 11 | normal | 323 | 2726.99 |
| 12 | normal | 370 | 6693.94 |

This is what i want my table to look like - Not sure if current month is supposed to look like that though.

| iMonth | strChannel | iOrderCount | fTurnover | iCurrentMonth | strCurrentDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | normal | 2234 | 33048.66 | 0 | 2021-12-22 13:54:09 |
| 1 | normal | 2234 | 33048.66 | 0 | 2022-01-22 13:54:09 |
| 2 | normal | 6638 | 66711.96 | 0 | 2022-02-22 13:54:09 |
| 3 | normal | 4266 | 30742.70 | 0 | 2022-03-22 13:54:09 |
| 4 | normal | 171 | 766.10 | 0 | 2022-04-22 13:54:09 |
| 5 | normal | 90 | 926.55 | 0 | 2022-05-22 13:54:09 |
| 6 | normal | 1254 | 12334.04 | 0 | 2022-06-22 13:54:09 |
| 7 | normal | 921 | 2990.35 | 0 | 2022-07-22 13:54:09 |
| 8 | normal | 9469 | 46407.63 | 0 | 2022-08-22 13:54:09 |
| 9 | normal | 5837 | 31623.17 | 0 | 2022-09-22 13:54:09 |
| 10 | normal | 70 | 305.03 | 0 | 2022-10-22 13:54:09 |
| 11 | normal | 323 | 2726.99 | 1 | 2022-10-22 13:54:09 |
| 12 | normal | 370 | 6693.94 | 0 | 2022-12-22 13:54:09 |
| 1 | b2b | 370 | 6693.94 | 0 | 2023-01-22 13:54:09 |
| 2 | normal | 370 | 6693.94 | 0 | 2023-02-22 13:54:09 |
| 3 | b2b | 370 | 6693.94 | 0 | 2023-03-22 13:54:09 |
| 4 | normal | 370 | 6693.94 | 0 | 2023-04-22 13:54:09 |

Hope it makes sense, but if i need to elaborate something then please ask :)

Comment: Execute `SELECT VERSION();` and show the output.

Comment: where will the data for the future 5 months originate from?

Comment: *shows a 17 month date interval* Does this means "current year completely + Dec of prev. year and Jan-Apr of next year"? or "current month + 11 months before + 5 months after"? or something else?

Comment: It seems that `strCurrentDate` makes no sense as DATETIME, and "year and month" is enough.

Comment: @Akina I get this output on version 5.7.38-41

Comment: Where does 'b2b' comes from?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - Our system logs stock orders and preorders. So we are able to see the amount of money a customer sold for on preorders. Hence we can get future dates

Comment: *version 5.7.38-41* Bad. No CTE or window functions... synthetic base calendar table should be used.

Comment: @Akina It doesn't mean current year completely, just 17 month - so current date plus 5 then rest backwards

Comment: @Serg B2B comes from a saleschannel. So which channel the customer recieve orders from

Comment: *just 17 month - so current date plus 5 then rest backwards* - i.e. month granularity, variant "current month + 11 months before + 5 months after". So generate statically the table with the numbers from -11 to +5, then generate calendar table, then use it as a base dates source table.

Comment: @Akina _i.e. month granularity, variant "current month + 11 months before + 5 months after_ That is correct yes, but the question now is how.

Comment: `s_order_main.channel` is neither   grouped nor  aggregated, it will take an arbitrary value for a month.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Provide source data (see "5. Some Additional Suggestions") which must result in shown desired output.

Comment: @Serg i added **strChannel** now to **GROUP BY** and i get both saleschannel for each month which it's supposed to, thanks. So far so good.

Comment: @Akina *Provide source data (see "5. Some Additional Suggestions") which must result in shown desired output* I'm not sure i understand what that means

Comment: *I'm not sure i understand what that means* Have you read the whole answer by provided link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if the current date/time is 2022-10-31 13:00:00 what should the end date/time for Feb 2022 grouping be? Obviously, it cannot be 2022-02-31 13:00:00. Should it be 2022-02-28 23:59:59?

Here is my attempt at your query. If you have a reliable (and/or dedicated) sequence table then you can get rid of the `seq` derived table.

```
SELECT
    MONTH(cal.monthStart)                           AS iMonth,
    s_order_main.channel                            AS strChannel,
    COUNT(DISTINCT s_order_styles.s_order_style_id) AS iOrderCount,
    SUM(DISTINCT s_order_styles.sales_price)        AS fTurnover,
    IF(DATE(cal.monthEnd) = CURRENT_DATE, 1, 0)     AS iCurrentMonth,
    cal.monthEnd                                    AS strCurrentDate
FROM (
    SELECT
        seq.n period,
        (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (DAY(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) DAY - INTERVAL (11 - seq.n) MONTH) monthStart,
        IF(
            DAY(CURRENT_DATE) > DAY((CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (11 - seq.n) MONTH)),
            LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (11 - seq.n) MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND,
            (NOW() - INTERVAL (11 - seq.n) MONTH)
        ) monthEnd
    FROM (
        SELECT  0 n UNION ALL SELECT  1 UNION ALL SELECT  2 UNION ALL SELECT  3 UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6 UNION ALL SELECT  7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL
        SELECT 10   UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15 UNION ALL SELECT 16
    ) seq
) cal
LEFT JOIN s_order_main
    ON s_order_main.added_date BETWEEN cal.monthStart AND cal.monthEnd
    AND s_order_main.order_type = 'pre'
LEFT JOIN s_order_styles
    ON s_order_styles.s_order_main_id = s_order_main.id
GROUP BY cal.period, strChannel;
```

Comment: Holy moly! That works! You are a lifesaver, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want some date arithmetic in your `WHERE`, kind of

```
 ..
   && s_order_main.added_date >= DATE_ADD(last_day(DATE_ADD(curdate(), interval -12 month)), interval 1 day)
   && s_order_main.added_date < DATE_ADD(last_day(DATE_ADD(curdate(), interval 5 month)), interval 1 day)
 ..
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cvLB9rfQ)